# MenuItem.Header and MenuItem.Icon DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem

I have a menu with the two following menu items:

```
<MenuItem Header="Item1">
  <MenuItem.Icon>
    <cc:Icon ImageSource="..." Size="22"/>
  </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem Header="Item2">
  <MenuItem.Icon>
    <cc:Icon ImageSource="..." Size="22"/>
  </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

As you can see each Item has a name as the "Header" and an Icon (my own control) as an an "Icon".

Instead of writing them explicitly in the XAML I want to Bind the `ItemsSource` to a `List<MenuItem>` object in my ViewModel, like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeMenu}"
```

My `MenuItem` class has the fields "String Name" and `ImageSource Icon` which I want to bind to the Header and the `Icon` parts of my menu item *exactly* how I did here.

I thought the right way was to use a `DataTemplate`, like this:

```
<Menu.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <!-- TODO: Bind the Header and Icon properties-->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    <!-- how to bind the icon? -->
  </DataTemplate>
<Menu.ItemTemplate>
```

But I don't understand how to define the Header and the `Icon` templates separately.

How do I accomplish this, than?

**update:** I want the `<cc:Icon>` to appear whereever in the menuItem template there is a `<contentPresenter Source="Icon">` and the `textBox` the appear whereever there is a `<contentPresenter Source="Header">`

Comment: i dont get it. you have your own control "Icon" in your namespace "cc". why cant you write <cc:Icon ImageSource="..." Size="22"/> right under your textblock? or <Image Source="youricon"/>

Comment: I don't... maybe that wasn't clear. I want the <cc:Icon> to appear whereever in the menuItem template there is a <contentPresenter Source="Icon"> and the textbox the appear whereever is a <contentPresenter Source="Header">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe this is what you want:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding SomeMenu}">
        <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Icon">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <cc:Icon Source="{Binding Icon}"></Image>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Style>
        </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>    
</Menu>
```

or did i fail miserably again? :)

Comment: I actually already used my Owen customer style, but I believe I can add those setters to it.

Comment: cool, do take a brief look at Menu.ItemContainerStyle vs Menu.ItemTemplate. certainly not a waste of time :b good luck